# curl command line is not opening

Tags: curl

Most of the research said me use curl for sending email.(I'm right this think?)

**Problem:** I downloaded this version of curl Win32 2000/XP **7.31.0** libcurl SSL Günter Knauf 3.32 MB. But command line did not open. Infact command line is opening. But cmdline instanly disappear when i clicked curl.exe. **My system info:** Windows 7 64 bit *note:* You can ask question why you download windows xp version. *Answer:* I did not find related verison of my system. Where can i download related version and how can i solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: try running `curl.exe` from within a `cmd.exe` console instead of clicking on it from Explorer

Comment: Have you tried running it in computability mode?

Comment: trying to open curl.exe with cmd.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, the curl you meant is a cli tool, so you should first open a terminal (console ?), and type curl command, you may want to read `man curl` for detail, how to use the tool. Simply double click curl won't work. (I am not familiar with windows stuff, correct me if I am wrong).

Also if you want to send email (via smtp), you need give related parameters. like `--mail-from, --mail-rcpt` ... again, read the manual of curl.

Answer (score 0):

It is closing instantly.
So, open the command line and directly to that folder(shortcut goto the bin folder & go to the address bar(ALT + D) and type 'cmd'). There type curl

Or if you want to open directly without going to that folder, set it in environment variable 'path' up to '/bin' like 'D:/sw/curl/bin'

If still does not works, download OpenSSL and open openssl.exe
and check typing 'version'

If curl still does not work download Mozilla certificate and keep it in 'C:\Windows\System32' file named "cacert.pem"

If still not running check if you are using any proxy, if yes
add --proxy  --proxy http://w.x.y.z:port w.x.y.z is ip, port is port number in proxy

Comment: Why you have down voted ? Atleast, write the reason. This is the solution I got. So, I posted it